# Can't display data retreived from firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read "publications" from my firebase database and then display it in Angular!

So I made a model "publication" in angular and I'm trying to retrieve the "publication" database using my service.

This is my database structure  :

[image]

**the service that I used: publication.service.ts**

```
   publications: Publication[] = [];
    PublicationsSubject = new Subject<Publication[]>();
    emitPublications() {
      this.PublicationsSubject.next(this.publications);
      console.log("in emit ", this.publications)
    }

  getPublications() {
    firebase.database().ref('/publications')
      .on('value', (data: firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => {
          this.publications = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
          this.emitPublications();
        }
      );
  }
```

**the model "publication" : publication.model.ts**

```
export class Publication {
    date_parution:  string ;
    numero:  string ;
    sommaire:  string ;
    tags:  string ;
    titre:  string ;
    titre_short:  string ;
    URL_achat:  string ;
    URL_couv:  string ;

    constructor(date_parution : string ,numero :string , sommaine : string , tags : string , titre : string , titre_short : string , 
      URL_achat:  string ,   URL_couv:  string ){
    }

  }
```

the componenet where i want to display the data 
 **publication-list.componenet.ts**

```
Publications: Publication[];
 PublicationsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private PublicationsService: PublicationsService , private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.PublicationsSubscription = this.PublicationsService.PublicationsSubject.subscribe(
      (publications: Publication[]) => {
        this.Publications = publications;
      }
    );
    this.PublicationsService.emitPublications();
  }
```

The problem is that I couldn't convert Publication object (the one that I retrieved from firebase ) to the Publication Array like the model that I made with typescript and that because the format of the object is `{ String , Publication }`  and in this case the string is the ID in firebase database

Any help please ?

Comment: create a interface rather than a class and pass it as type 
export interface Publication {
    date_parution:  string ;
    numero:  string ;
    sommaire:  string ;
    tags:  string ;
    titre:  string ;
    titre_short:  string ;
    URL_achat:  string ;
    URL_couv:  string ;

  }

Also can you confirm you are getting json response from your firebase database api.

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore should work with class as long as he does not have to use some class methods as there is no runtime class controll.

Comment: the class and the  interface works the same .

Comment: the problem is with the ID of each record in that database ! because usually the ID is a number and in my case it is a string